# How to replace the contents of out.txt with in.txt in a third file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I have three files, `main.txt`, `out.txt` and `in.txt`. I want to replace every occurrence of the contents of `out.txt` in `main.txt` with the contents of `in.txt`.

Both `out.txt` and `in.txt` may contain multiple lines and all sorts of special characters. How do I properly read and escape these strings?

Here is an example containing some edge cases like special characters, repeated matches, uncomplete matches, overlapping matches.

**`main.txt`:**

```
foo
Replace these
three lines
with some $.*\'"& in it
bar
Replace these
three lines
with some $.*\'"& in it
Replace these
three lines
with some $.*\'"& in it

three lines
Replace these
three lines
three lines
with some $.*\'"& in it
baz
```

**`out.txt`:**

```
Replace these
three lines
with some $.*\'"& in it
```

**`in.txt`:**

```
Replacement lines
also with $.*\'"&
```

**Expected output:**

```
foo
Replacement lines
also with $.*\'"&
bar
Replacement lines
also with $.*\'"&
Replacement lines
also with $.*\'"&

three lines
Replace these
three lines
three lines
with some $.*\'"& in it
baz
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome here. We're not a free code-writing service, but we aim to help. Can you explain what you've tried so far and where you're stuck? Otherwise, your question is just too broad.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I fail to see in which way that is too broad. Sounds like a simple text-processing questions like there are thousands of here.

Comment: [edit] your question to contain concise, testable sample input and expected output that covers all of your test cases to demonstrate your needs and so we can copy/paste it to test with. Make sure to include regexp metachars (e.g. `.` and `*`) in out.txt, backreferences in in.txt (e.g. `&` and `\1`), substrings (e.g. `the` in in.txt and `there` in main.txt), upper/lower case (`the` in one vs `The` in another), and punctuation (`foo.` and `foo's`) as those are the common failure points for scripts for tasks like this. Also add your code attempt to solve the problem so we can help you with that.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas FWIW I agree with Marcus that so far the question is too broad as we don't know the OPs requirements for any of the details [I just requested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/746023/how-to-replace-the-contents-of-out-txt-with-in-txt-in-a-third-file#comment1418923_746023). We don't even know if the "string" (presumed since they asked to escape chars) contents of out.txt is a list of "words" one line at a time, or a single line of words, or a list of multi-word sentences, how the "strings" are separated, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `perl`:

```bash
perl -0777 -e '$out = <>; $in = <>; $_ = <>; s/\Q$out\E/$in/g; print
              ' out.txt in.txt main.txt > new-main.txt
```

Should work whatever characters or non-characters (also works for binary files) the files may contain as long as they are small enough to fit in memory.

`-0777` sets the input record separator to something impossible, same as doing `$/ = undef`, so the `<>` which reads in turn from the files¹ passed as arguments reads the files whole.

So we have `$out`/`$in`/`$_` containing the full contents of `out.txt`, `in.txt` and `main.txt` respectively.

`$_` is the variable the `s/pattern/replacement/flags` operator works on by default and that `print` prints by default, the equivalent of the *pattern space* in `sed`.

Here the pattern  is `\Q$out\E` where the `\Q...\E` causes what's inside to be treated literally, not as a regexp. The `g` flag is to replace all occurrences like in `sed`.

---

<sup>¹ or command outputs such as `ls|`, use `<<>>` instead for those to only be interpreted as file paths</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
FILENAME == ARGV[1] { old = old $0 ORS }
FILENAME == ARGV[2] { new = new $0 ORS }
FILENAME == ARGV[3] { rec = rec $0 ORS }
END {
    lgth = length(old)
    if ( lgth > 0 ) {
        while ( beg = index(rec,old) ) {
            printf "%s%s", substr(rec,1,beg-1), new
            rec = substr(rec,beg+lgth)
        }
    }
    printf "%s", rec
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk out.txt in.txt main.txt
foo
Replacement lines
also with $.*\'"&
bar
Replacement lines
also with $.*\'"&
Replacement lines
also with $.*\'"&

three lines
Replace these
three lines
three lines
with some $.*\'"& in it
baz
```

The above is doing literal string matching and substitution so it'll work for any characters in the input files.

Answer (score 0):

If your shell does support `<()` (like `zsh`, `ksh`, `bash`), you can insert markings between the files (here: `MARK`) to separate them and use any POSIX `sed`:

```
sed -e 'H;1h;$!d;x;:L
        s/^\(.*\)\(MARK\n\)\(.*\)\2\(.*\)\1/\1\2\3\2\4\3/;tL
        s/.*MARK\n//' out.txt <(echo MARK) in.txt <(echo MARK) main.txt
```

- `H;1h;$!d;x` is the typical pattern to process the whole file in one
- `:L`starts a loop
- `s/^\(.*\)\(MARK\n\)\(.*\)\2\(.*\)\1/\1\2\3\2\4\3/` replaces `out.txt` by `in.txt`
- `tL` loops as long as a replacement could be made
- `s/.*MARK\n//` removes the other files before printing

Please note the restrictions:

1. Obviously, you need to choose a `MARK` that is not part of the text.
2. As commented, this may fail for big files, depending on your `sed` implementation. I never did hit this border on modern system, but it is existing. FLushing lines without match would solve this, but that start to be programming, which is not what `sed` was made for.

Comment: Note that POSIX compliant `sed` are not required to support pattern and hold spaces larger than 8KiB so that would only works for very small files with some implementations.

Comment: THank you, @StéphaneChazelas I added that restriction.